# Why the value of goal is null?

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel, mobile-development

I am trying to send data from Quiz1Fragment to HomeFragment using SharedViewModel.

I have observed the log statements in SharedViewModel, and the goal is correctly set.

The issue seems to be with the observation or retrieval of the goal value in HomeFragment.

I have already tried observing changes in HomeFragment using LiveData, but the TextView still displays null.

**Logcat**:`

D  Setting goal in SharedViewModel: 200

E  Goal is null

Can someone fin any solutions?

**HomeFragment**

```
   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
TextView textView;
SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCalories);
    sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);


    Integer goal = sharedViewModel.getSelectedGoal().getValue();
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(goal));

    return view;
}
```

}

**SharedViewModel**

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<Integer> selectGoal = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void setSelectGoal(int goal){
    Log.d("SharedViewModel", "Setting goal in SharedViewModel: " + goal);
    selectGoal.setValue(goal);
}

public LiveData<Integer> getSelectedGoal(){
    return selectGoal;
}
```

}

**Quiz1Fragment**

```
public class Quiz1Fragment extends Fragment {

private SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_quiz1, container, false);

    RadioGroup radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int goal = 0;
            if (checkedId == R.id.lose) {
                goal = 100;
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.gain) {
                goal = 200;
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.maintain) {
                goal = 300;
            }
            sharedViewModel.setSelectGoal(goal);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should observe `liveData` this way. The data may not have changed when the `fragment` was created. You cannot catch this because `onCreateView` will run once. This way, it will be triggered with every data change.

```
    sharedViewModel.getSelectedGoal().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer goal) {
            if (goal != null) {
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(goal));
            } else {
                Log.e("Goal", "Goal is null");
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
```

Comment: I tried this method and now nothing appears in the textview, not even null